# Read PHP response

Tags: javascript, php

How to put "75150" in console.log? (see image), the php is not access.

```
success: function (response) {  
                  console.log(response);
                  
                  let tasks = JSON.parse(response);
                  let precio = tasks[0];
                  let template = '';
                  template += `
                  <p>${tasks}</p>
                  `
                  $('#relleno').html(template);
                  console.log(tasks);
                  console.log(response);
                  console.log(precio);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `console.log(precio[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to tell what is going on in the image provided. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in future.

However, it looks like `tasks` is an array of objects with the following structure:

```js
{
  0: "some string",
  Valor_Flete: "the same string",
}
```

In that case, you can get the value `75150` from the `0` field like so:

```js
console.log(tasks[0][0]);
```

Or from the `Valor_Flete` field like so:

```js
console.log(tasks[0].Valor_Flete);
```